# If answer applies to the question but is from someone spamming, do we leave it or kill it

Tags: discussion, answers, spam

Just saw this in the first posts review queue:

https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/37870

[image]

... and even while looking at it the downvotes kicked in (from -1 to -3),
 so it will probably be gone in a few seconds:

[Question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/25741/simple-program-to-cut-videos-without-any-loss-of-quality-for-windows-linux-or-a)
[Answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/56450/416) <sup>*</sup>

This raises the question with me:

OK, so it's a spammer, but what if the answer applies to the question?
Do we still delete it as spam?

Notes:

- It's not a high quality answer but leave that aside for moment.
- The *Known spammer* comment link disappeared while I was typing this up. I think this link contributed to the quick downvotes.
- <del>I have given the answer an upvote to preserve it.</del><sup>*</sup>
- My tendency is to leave the answer but comment asking for affiliation (which I did)

<sup>* Answer has been deleted now</sup>

Comment: The link pointed to Metasmoke. The domain used by the now deleted answer is a spam domain – and in that case I'm definitely pro nuke.

Answer (score 0):

The general guidance is to judge each post on its own merits.

If the spammers learn the rules and start to behave, more power to them.  The memetic standard reference is https://xkcd.com/810/

I'm undecided on this particular case; but if many of us refrain from flagging as spam, I guess that sort of establishes it as not spam, effectively.

(For what it's worth, I am not a regular on this particular site, but I regularly flag spam as a volunteer in [Charcoal](https://charcoal-se.org/) and some of it happens to be on this site.)